# How to check that only one object of many is non-null?

Tags: java

Only one object of three must not be null, two others must be null. The obvious naive solution would be like that:

```
    if (param1 != null && param2 == null && param3 == null) {
        doSomething(param1);
    } else if (param1 == null && param2 != null && param3 == null) {
        doSomethingElse(param2);
    } else if (param1 == null && param2 == null && param3 != null) {
        doOtherThings(param3);
    }
```

Is there more elegant solution to ensure that only one object is not null?

Comment: Are there really 3 separate handling methods here, or is there just one logical flow?

Comment: Do you want to check if exactly one object is non-null or want to find the only non-null element and invoke a method corresponding to the param?

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen 
 yes, there are three separate handling methods.

Comment: @user7 need to check it exactly for each object, because handling methods are different for each of them.

Comment: I think you should probably be using an Interface.

Comment: If it's just 3 things, I'd stick with what you've got.

Comment: The most elegant solution is to not have three params in the first place.

Comment: Could you show more context? For instance, what type(s) are the params?

Comment: You could do `if (param1 != null && Stream.of(param2, param3).noneMatch(Objects::nonNull))`; but I don't feel that's an improvement.

Comment: @AndyTurner Yes, here Stream might reduce the performance also.

Comment: @MC Emperor, all params come from query request parameters, all are of type String. The handling is different for each of them.

Comment: @Stanja you can introduce new method to make code more clean but complexity cannot reduce.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I would maybe rethink the design of having all different parameters of which just a single one must be nonnull.

But anyways, you need to take two actions:

- check if exactly one param is nonnull
- then invoke a method based on the parameter which is nonnull.

You *could* achieve this by first writing a method which returns the position of the nonnull index of a list of params, but only if that's the only nonnull value:

```java
OptionalInt nonnullIndex(List<?> params) {
    var nonnulls = IntStream.range(0, params.size())
        .filter(i -> params.get(i) != null)
        .toArray();
    return (nonnulls.length == 1 ? OptionalInt.of(nonnulls[0]) : OptionalInt.empty());
}
```

And then you could create a list of `Consumer`s which each invoke their own method:

```java
List<Consumer<String>> consumers = List.of(
    s -> doSomething(s),
    s -> doSomethingElse(s),
    s -> doOtherThings(s)
);

List<String> params = Arrays.asList(param1, param2, param3);
int index = nonnullIndex(params)
    .orElseThrow(IllegalArgumentException::new);
consumers.get(index).accept(params.get(index));
```

At last, I totally [agree with](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69404589/how-to-check-that-only-one-object-of-many-is-non-null/69405288#comment122672361_69404589) Andy Turner:

> If it's just 3 things, I'd stick with what you've got.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer to use Stream to check these parameters.

```java
if (Stream.of(param1, param2, param3).filter(Objects::nonNull).count() != 1) {
    throw new Exception();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, I think what you have is fine. It's a little bit messy to look at, and error-prone (getting the param number wrong, getting `!=` and `==` mixed up); but almost anything you do will just make it harder to understand at a glance.

For example, you could introduce a method like this:

```
boolean onlyFirstNonNull(Object first, Object second, Object third) {
  return first != null && second == null && third == null;
}
```

(You can make it variadic on the "must be null" parameters, but that's unnecessary here since you're always doing 3 things)

and invoke like

```
    if (onlyFirstNonNull(param1, param2, param3)) {
        doSomething(param1);
    } else if (onlyFirstNonNull(param2, param1, param3)) {
        doSomethingElse(param2);
    } else if (onlyFirstNonNull(param3, param1, param2)) {
        doOtherThings(param3);
    }
```

This gets around the problem of mixing up `!=` and `==`; but it's still easy to mix up param numbers; and the method isn't standard, so you don't necessarily grok what it means at a glance.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array and simply count nulls in a loop. This should work well if there are more than just three elements, and we are checking for exactly **one** null between them:

```
Object [] elements = { "a", null, "b" };
int s = 0;
for (int p = 0; p < elements.length; p++) {
    if (elements[p] == null) {
        s++;
    }
}
boolean oneNull = s == 1;
```

At the time of answering, nowhere in the header or text of the question is written about the need to know which element is null.

Comment: That identifies that one thing is null, but it doesn't identify which.

Comment: Have not been asked for, at least deciding from the title of the question.

Comment: of course it's been asked for: OP wants to do a particular thing depending on which of the params isn't null.

Comment: The question is "How to check that only one object of many is null?"

Comment: You have to read beyond the title. That's why you have to write more than the title when posting a question.

Comment: Yes, corrected now.

Comment: "nowhere in the header or text of the question is written about the need to know which element is null" other than the code in the [original text of the question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/69404589/1) (and all subsequent revisions), which shows that OP wants to do a different things depending on which of the params is non-null.

Answer (score 0):

You can perform the enforcing the requirement of having exactly one non-null param as a precondition.

```java
boolean hasExactlyOneNonNullParam = List.of(param1, param2, param3)
  .stream()
  .filter(Objects::nonNull)
  .count() == 1;

if (!hasExactlyOneNonNullParam) {
  // handle failed precondition
  return;
}

if (param1 != null) {
    doSomething(param1);
} else if (param2 != null) {
    doSomethingElse(param2);
} else {
    doOtherThings(param3);
}
```

Comment: `List.of` is null-hostile: it would throw if any of the params are null.

Comment: You seem to be trying to set a boolean variable to a list object.

Comment: My bad, code snippet was incomplete. Fixed it now.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a method using varargs and count the non-null objects.

```
public static long getCountOfNonNullObjects(Object ... objects)
{
    return Arrays.stream(objects).filter(Objects::nonNull).count();
}
```

Then you can use your if statement like this

```
if (getCountOfNonNullObjects(obj,obj,obj) == 1)
    doSomething();
```

Note: You can use as many objects as you want

Answer (score 0):

I think you should stick with what you have. But if you want to confuse your co-workers or your feature-self something like below should be eqivalent:

```
String res = "";
res += param1 == null ? 0:1;
res += param2 == null ? 0:1;
res += param3 == null ? 0:1;
    
switch (res){
    case "100": doSomething(param1);     break;
    case "010": doSomethingElse(param2); break;
    case "001": doOtherThings(param3);   break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to add another option:

```
int action = 0;
if (param1 != null) {
    if (action == 0) action = 1;
    else  /* throw some error */;
}
if (param2 != null) {
    if (action == 0) action = 2;
    else  /* throw some error */;
}
if (param3 != null) {
    if (action == 0) action = 3;
    else  /* throw some error */;
}
switch (action) {
    case 1: soSomething(); break;
    case 2: doSomethingElse(); break;
    case 3: doOtherThings(); break;
    else:   /* throw error */;
}
```

The first 3 ifs are very similar. And the method can easily be used to process an array of arguments (set action to `i + 1`, where `i` is the variable used to iterate through the array).

Answer (score 0):

The methods inside you if conditions are different from each other the complexity of your code cannot reduce. Yet you can make your code more clean like follows,

*Note: Here I have assumed your `params` are type `String`*

```
public boolean execute(String param , String... params) {
    return param != null && Arrays.stream(params).filter(Objects::isNull).count() == 2;
}
```

```
if      (execute(param1, param2, param3)) {doSomething(param1);}
else if (execute(param2, param1, param3)) {doSomethingElse(param2);}
else if (execute(param3, param1, param2)) {doOtherThings(param3);}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or with Enum call `ParamEnum.doSomething(par1, par2, par3)`

```
public enum ParamEnum {
    PARAM1 {
        @Override
        protected boolean accepted(String par1, String par2, String par3) {
            return par1 != null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void doOperation() {
            doSomethingImportant();
        }
    }, PARAM2 {
        @Override
        protected boolean accepted(String par1, String par2, String par3) {
            return par2 != null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void doOperation() {
            doSomethingElse();
        }
    }, PARAM3 {
        @Override
        protected boolean accepted(String par1, String par2, String par3) {
            return par3 != null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void doOperation() {
            doOtherThings();
        }
    };

    public static void doSomething(String par1, String par2, String par3) {
        List<ParamEnum> paramEnums =
                Arrays.stream(ParamEnum.values()).filter(e -> e.accepted(par1, par2, par3)).collect(Collectors.toList());
        if(paramEnums.size() == 1) {
            paramEnums.get(0).doOperation();
        }
    }

    abstract boolean accepted(String par1, String par2, String par3);
    abstract void doOperation();
}
```